# Input type file - wrap long file name text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to wrap the file name text that appears beside the browse button?

I have a simple upload button

```
<input type="file" />
```

I'm uploading a file with a very long name, you can see that a horizontal scrollbar has appeared to enable reading the full text:

[image]

I've tried tinkering with the css but it adds an ellipsis and i can't figure out a way to show the full file name without horizontal scrollbars.

```
input[type="file"] {
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: Which browser is it, as now-a-days browsers hide the full path.

Comment: You can add some `php` or `javascript` for shortern/hide the filename. The path is hidden by default.

Comment: The browser i'm using is Firefox v60.  

I don't want to shorten/hide the filename as i want the user to be able to read the full file name.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with JavaScript. A solution might look like this:

```js
function update(e) {
  fileName.textContent = file.files[0].name;
}

const file = document.querySelector('#file'),
      fileName = document.querySelector('.file-name');

file.addEventListener('change', update);
```

```css
.file-button {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

.file-name {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 2px;
}

input[type='file'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="file-label" for="file">Profile picture:
  <div class="file-button">Browse&hellip;</div>
</label>
<p class="file-name">No file selected.</p>
<input id="file" type="file">
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
input[type="file"] {
width:100vw;
max-width:100%;  
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

and if someone wants to give it a width, you can add it to the parent element
for exapmle add this to the label:

```
{ 
display: block;
width: 200px;
}
```